# Is there a way I can replicate http traffic to a redundant server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, proxy

I will be moving a high load prod system over to new hardware over the next few weeks.  However in the mean time I would like to validate that the new hardware will handle the expected loads.  I would really like to stick some kind of 'proxy' infront of the current web server and copy all that http traffic to the new environment, i.e. run them both in parallel.

Ideally this proxy would also validate that the responses are the same.

I can then monitor the new hardware stats (cpu, mem, etc) and see if it looks ok.

What is this kind of proxy called?  Any one have any suggestions?  This is for a Windows .Net (asp.net) and SQL server environment.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish comes to mind - https://www.varnish-cache.org/

**Edit**
I'd actually use nginx... (two years experience after answering this question).. varnish would be silly to use. nginx would definitely be the better option.

Comment: Looks like Varnish just has a load balancer, which is not what I'm really after, I'm after a traffic replicator.  I.e. I want to put the new environment under the same load as the existing.

Comment: Well it is a reverse caching proxy, however, you could use it in order to pass **all** traffic through to that server. You just would have it configured to cache nothing, so that each request on server A, results in a pass request on server B. I would in my opinion be ideal for the environment you have suggested.

Comment: After some more reading looks like may be a good solution, Thanks Layke

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). It's Java based but allows you to record user journeys and play them back in bulk for stress testing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the option of recording / playbak of http events, but was after something more like the traffic replication idea.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by traffic replication? JMeter can replicate huge volumes of traffic.